# How to tell jackson to serialize to json without attributes prefix

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson2

In my Java IDE, I tell java that I use prefix for my fields.

The result is that during a Java to Json serialization, I get all my attributes prefixed with an `_`, is there a simple way to do so ?

**Actual**

```
{
  "_creation": {
    "_dateTime": "2016-08-16T11:13:09.000Z",
    "_personId": 1
  },
  "_description": null,
  "_firstName": "Jason",
  "_id": 700,
  "_lastName": "Stateman",
  "_modification": {
    "_dateTime": "2016-08-16T11:13:24.000Z",
    "_personId": null
  }
}
```

**Wanted**

```
{
  "creation": {
    "dateTime": "2016-08-16T11:13:09.000Z",
    "personId": 1
  },
  "description": null,
  "firstName": "Jason",
  "id": 700,
  "lastName": "Stateman",
  "modification": {
    "dateTime": "2016-08-16T11:13:24.000Z",
    "personId": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just tell your IDE ***not*** to prefix your fields??

Comment: `I tell java that I use prefix for my fields.` why would you ever do that?

Comment: Can you copy/paste your Java POJO, you are serializing, most likely you will be able to do it with Jackson annotations, most likely @JsonProperty to tell Jackson what is the actual name of your property at serialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FasterXML to serialize your objects, you could add the @JsonProperty annotation to your class attributes to control the serialized attribute name. See the documentation at : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-naming